# Wait for multiple Promise to return data in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have below given code in a javascript file,

```
class APIMessage
{
    isReady()
        {
            return cy.request({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/isready"
            
            }).then(res => {
                return new Promise((resolve) => {
                    resolve(res);
                })
            })
        }

    receiveMsg()
    {
        return cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/getMsg"
            
        }).then(res => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                resolve(res);
            })
        })
    }

    async GetMessage()
        {
            const status =  await this.isReady()
            
            if(status.body.send == true)
            {
                var message =  await this.receiveMsg()
                cy.log("-- ",message)
            }
        }
}
var msg = new APIMessage()
export default msg
```

this `GetMessage()` I am able to import to it block of cypress, and use as

```
it("Receive Message",function(){
        msg.GetMessage()
    })
```

the test case calls `GetMessage()`, gets `isReady` status, enters if block but fails to print `message`, even though the API works fine, also it ends the test case successfully here without executing remaining statements.